# jQuery css modifier, use a javascript variable

Tags: jquery

I have this line of jQuery:

```
$("#colorimage").css('background','url(images/bw.jpg)');
```

First question: the way that this is working, when the background image is set with CSS via jQuery, from where is it looking for the images folder?

Second question: is there a way I can insert a Javascript variable into the second argument? I have a base url stored in a js variable but doing something like this:

```
$("#colorimage").css('background','url(' +  baseurl + 'images/bw.jpg)');
```

doesn't work.

**EDIT:**
baseurl is a Javascript variable, right now it is http://localhost/test/ but it will be changing, which is why I want to use a variable.

**EDIT 2:** It was a path problem, thank you guys for the answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1:**  jQuery will be setting the css of the background image to 'url(images/bw.jpg)' in exactly the same way as if you changed the css directly.  In other words, if it's in a css file, it'll be relative to that css file.  If it's inline, it'll be relative to the page.

**Question 2:**  Have a look at nickf's answer - the only reason that wouldn't be working is that it's not the right path.

EDIT: Try examining the contents of the baseurl variable (firebug or even `alert()`).  I can't see why that wouldn't work unless the path was pointing to the wrong spot.

Answer (score 2):

It will take the url from the location of the file in which it is applied, so if your page is `http://mysite.com/index.html`, it will be looking at `http://mysite.com/images/bw.jpg`

Try making your baseurl absolute by putting a slash at the start, or use a full URL

```
baseurl = "/mySubFolder";
baseurl = "http://mysite.com/mySubFolder";
```

Comment: Nit-picking, but for his example, a trailing forwardslash would be necessary. +1 anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
$("#colorimage").css('background-image','url(' +  baseurl + 'images/bw.jpg)');
```

Comment: Do you mean "background-image" instead of "background-url"? ;)